# How can i post data and file by using ajax on event onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

HTML here.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="file" name="userImage">
  <button onclick="post('./example.php')" type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now i want to post it by using post() function

Java-script:

```js
Function post(url){
   $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#myform").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
           alert("successfully posted.");
        }
    });
}
```

> But not serialized file

Comment: And what is your problem? Please define the actual problem in your question and update it.

Comment: Actual problem is File Not serialized.

Comment: u mean form data is not serialized?

Comment: you must define url in your function when you call `post('http://exmple.com')`

Comment: Did you include jquery lib before calling that function?

Comment: Yes, jquery lib included.
only file not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: try to have apart html and js defining the event callback on "attacheventlistener" function or "on" jquery's function (this way is easier).

Your problem is that you are passing the string "url" when you need pass a valid url, so write the url directly on ajax url field or define a data attribute on your form tag, e.g. data-url="http://whatever", and catch this value from the event.

If you use jquery's "on" function is extremly easy, you could to get it data's value via jquery's "data" function over "this" var.

Something like ...

```
$("#myForm").on("click", 
      function() {
            post(this.data("url"));
});
```

But probably you do not need url being a var.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that nothing is being posted.
The thing is is that you are trying to do a file upload via ajax, this is not wrong but it needs to be done differently shown here: 
[jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload#2320097)

Answer (score 0):

First of all i need to say that, if you want to upload file, i mean if your form have file input then add the form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` according to [RFC-7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#page-4). you can also see the uses http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp.

Then move to the html part again. Suppose you have a form input like

```
<form action="some_domain/example.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileId"/>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="name">
    <button onclick="post('some_domain/example.php')" type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Now post the file data using ajax:

```
function post(url){
   $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'POST',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        data: $('#fileId')[0].files[0],
        success: function (data) {
           alert("successfully posted.");
        }
    });
}
```

I think this should be worked fine.

**UPDATE:**
if you want to post text data as well then you should use `FormData` object.

```
function post(url){
var formData = new FormData();
   var files = document.getElementById("fileId").files;
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       var file = files[i];
       formData.append('files[]', file, file.name);
}
formData.append('firstName',$('#name').val());
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'POST',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
           alert("successfully posted.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to post  Both  Text field data and file,
With without Reload

Comment: its so difficult  `formData.append('firstName',$('#name').val());`

Comment: You can iterate all of the text node by `var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');` and iterate with that `nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra data with form data

use serializeArray and add the additional data:

```
var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'tienn2t', value: 'love'});
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "your url.php",
data: data,
dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
         //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
        // do what ever you want with the server response
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error handing here');
   });
```